# Primeng Datatable - How to add styles to particular tr element when a button is clicked in that row

Tags: css, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using p-datatable in my angular project. [image]

When I click Delete in that row, I want to add just "display: none" style to that row since I want to just hide it and not delete it. The element will actually get deleted only when the user click the final save button. Can someone sugegst me how to pass tr element into my action

This how my code looks

```
<p-column *ngIf="configuration.RowQuickActions">
         <ng-template let-dataRow="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <div style="text-align: center">
               <a class="action-icon">
                  <i class="material-icons text-center" [mdMenuTriggerFor]="rowQuickActionMenu">more_vert</i>
               </a>
            </div>
            <md-menu #rowQuickActionMenu="mdMenu" xPosition="before" [overlapTrigger]="false">
               <a *ngFor="let action of configuration.RowQuickActions" class="datatable-quick-action" (click)="performRowQuickAction(action, dataRow)" md-menu-item>
                  <i *ngIf="action.ActionIcon" class="material-icons">{{action.ActionIcon}}</i>{{action.ActionName}}</a>
            </md-menu>
         </ng-template>
      </p-column>
```

There can be many actions and many datatables use this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  [[ngClass]](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass). You can write function, which return "display: none" when button was clicked and "" otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

use [ngStyle] Directive for Hide you row

Answer (score 0):

In your delete function add the css

```
style="display: none"
```

or If you want to apply the styles to inner elements which are associated to `p-DataTable` then use `styleClass`

**Example:**

`<p-datatable="InputData"styleClass="input-data">`

in your CSS:

```
.input-data{
 display:none;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I updated the prime ng datatable to latest revision (TurboTable) and the new code has tr tags so just added the below one in the html

```js
<tr *ngIf="!dataRow.hide">
```

and in the method in the component I have added this.

```js
performRowQuickAction(action, dataRow) {
  dataRow.Hide = true;
  // do other things
}
```

Thanks everyone for the help.